# Filevault recovery issue on dead Macbook OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, data-recovery, osx-yosemite

My daughter spilled rum into her MacBook, and it has died. No screen, no proper boot, just a ping when first turned on.

The harddrive did survive, but when I attach it to my Mac mini, there are no files of note in her Users/hername directory.

Same for her timemachine backup hard drive.

I can access both HD via USB adapter, but can't find any information on them.

1. Does filevault protect only her Users files? everything else appears to be unencrypted and fine, although the Mac mini of course won't actually boot her version of Mac OS X.
2. When I perform a recovery, I can restore her files to my Mac Mini, which gives me a login under her password and user name.  Still no files in the Users/hername folder.
3. If not a filevault issue, any idea what could have happened
4. If it is a filevault issue, how do I recover if the original Macbook is dead?